# Outlier treatment in R

Tags: r

I am very new to the programming language R. Please forgive my extremely basic questions, which might appear a bit odd to a lot of professionals.

My data set has 3 parameters `Lead_Time`, `Gross`, and `Stay_days`. Using box plot i can't get clear outliers. 
I have used this command

```
outlier1 <- boxplot.stats(var_name)$out
var_name2 <- ifelse(var_name %in% outlier1, NA, var_name)
```

Now the above commands replaces the Outlier value with NAs. My question is on the basis of what this command is picking the outlier values?

2) One i have the NAs, I want to replace all the NAs with mean or median.

Should i use the mean or median of var_name2( meaning minus the outliers)
If yes, how do i do that?

I used this

```
m1<-mean(var_name2, na.rm= T)
var_name3<-ifelse(is.na(var_name2)==TRUE, m1,var_name2)
```

However when i see the summary of `var_name3` and `var_name2` - the results are same

Comment: You should edit your post to format the code using the ` marks around it

Comment: Is your first question about how `boxplot.stats()` determines outliers?  If so, that's mentioned in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I doubt the statistical soundness of your procedure. Why do you want to replace the "outliers", what ever that means, with means or medians? Just look at the following example.

```
set.seed(3212)
var_name <- rnorm(1e3)
bp <- boxplot(var_name)
length(bp$out)
[1] 9
```

So you see that we have perfectly good gaussian numbers, but the boxplot displays 9 outliers. It's OK. If you repeat an experiment enough times, values outside the "usual" will show up.
As for your first question, notice that I've saved the value of function `boxplot` in a variable named `bp`. If you see the help page for `boxplot` you'll see that the return value is a named list with an element named `out`. These are the outliers.

2) The summary values of `var_name2` and `var_name3` are not the same, at least not with the data example I've created.

```
outlier1 <- boxplot.stats(var_name)$out
var_name2 <- ifelse(var_name %in% outlier1, NA, var_name)
m1<-mean(var_name2, na.rm= T)
var_name3<-ifelse(is.na(var_name2)==TRUE, m1,var_name2)

summary(var_name2)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
-2.70820 -0.71652 -0.04224 -0.04739  0.59690  2.58625        9 
summary(var_name3)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-2.70820 -0.71250 -0.04739 -0.04739  0.58591  2.58625
```